# Undefined variable inside a closure in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem with Laravel, PHP and Blade

```
@for ($i=1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{!!           
    ($substance->consumptions->filter(function($consumption, $key){
        return $consumption->date->month == $i;
    })->sum('quantity'))
!!},
@endfor
```

Undefined variable: i (View: /Users/luisalcaras/Projects/piba_web/resources/views/index.blade.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `'use'` keyword to pass variables from the parent scope to the closure:

```
@for ($i=1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{!!           
    ($substance->consumptions->filter(function($consumption, $key) use ($i){
        return $consumption->date->month == $i;
    })->sum('quantity'))
!!},
@endfor
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

try this?

```
@for ($i=1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{!!           
    ($substance->consumptions->filter(function($consumption, $key){
        global $i;
        return $consumption->date->month == $i;
    })->sum('quantity'))
!!},
@endfor
```

Comment: Global?!  One of the beautiful things about Laravel is that you don't have to hack it by using things like `global`  --  `use` is the preferred method to changing `scope`!